# Copy whatsApp Database to my pc

Tags: data-recovery, whatsapp-messenger

I am using Sony Xperia P and my display is not working. So I am not able to do any thing with my mobile.
Now I want to copy my WhatsApp database to another android phone or PC.But I am not able to do so.And every time I tried to copy database folder of WhatsApp to my PC ,it shows msgdbstore.crypt files in phones storage,but the copied folder is empty.
Thanks in advance ,please give suggestion how to copy database.

Comment: What happens if you try to copy just the latest backup file, not the entire folder?

Comment: At least related: [Transfer Whatsapp chat history to new device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74973/16575) / [How can I read the chat logs from WhatsApp messenger on my Windows machine?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61317/16575) / [How to transfer WhatsApp conversations to a new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62237/16575)

Comment: @Onik not able to copy any files.

Comment: What mode are you connecting the phone in? MTP? PTP? Mass storage? ADB?